# How to print out line found and line after line found in bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, text

I have a .txt file that prints out hundreds of lines of text that are the results of many test. At the beginning of the test it says

LAUNCH TEST: {nameOfTest}.

Then proceeds to print out which test passed and which failed. At the end of test it prints out

============================================
Ran 3 tests in 0.000 seconds, 3 successes, 0 failures

These are two lines in the .txt files. What I want to do print out the LAUNCH TEST and the results of the test.

I know I can iterate over every line of the txt file like so:

```
cat ~/sample.txt | while read line; do
    #Then compare "$line" with what I am searching for
```

So the question is how do I search for lines "containing" certain string then print it?

Something like,

```
if [[ "$line" == *"LAUNCH TEST"* ]]; then
            echo $line
            echo "This was the test found"
    fi
```

But for some reason this comparison does not work inside of that while loop.

Comment: There is a tool called `grep` for exactly that purpose, you might want to consider using it.

Comment: can you post your input example where we could see at least two matches?

Comment: @LarsFischer do you have any examples?

Comment: Your snippets work for me. Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're seeing. Or (as Lars suggested) try `grep` instead of a shell loop.

Comment: `*` is expanded to a list of filenames

Comment: Your question is really not clear. At some point you mention to print "LAUNCH TEST" and the "results of the test" (dashed line or something else, we don't know). Then you ask later "the question is how do I search for lines "containing" certain string then print it?" which is not the same thing asked in the beginning. Please clarify your question and add an example with input and output desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print a matching line **and the line that follows** the match you can use awk:

```
awk '/LAUNCH TEST/{print $0; flag=1; next} {if (flag) print $0;} /.*/{flag=0} '  ~/sample.txt
```

This script demonstrates the typical awk idiom of using a 'flag' variable to turn printing on and off for certain lines. Note the use of the `next` command to prevent printing the matched line twice.

With `grep` you can use the `-A1` argument to simply print the next line

```
grep -A1 ~/sample.txt
```

However, grep will put a line with a double-dash in between each match. You can get rid of that by piping through grep but that runs the *possible* risk of eliminating a legitimate line that *happens* to be a double-dash itself.

Comment: If the printing of the filename is not desired you can build a pipe like this: `cat filename | grep -A1 "LAUNCH TEST" `. Then grep does not see `filename` and only prints the text.